# Flutter mapEventToState is not called though event was fired

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

mapEventToState is called only for 2,3 times then it is not called.
I am making signalr chatting application in flutter. And when internet is off it should fire disconnect event and when internet is available it fires connect event.

For example:

```
abstract class SocketEvent extends Equatable {
  const SocketEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class SocketConnectRequested extends SocketEvent {
  const SocketConnectRequested();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class SocketDisconnectRequested extends SocketEvent {
  const SocketDisconnectRequested();
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
}
```

and for internet sense code:

```
_subscription =
        Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectivityResult) async{
          print(state.status);
          if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
            add(SocketConnectRequested());
          } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
            add(SocketConnectRequested());
          } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
            add(SocketDisconnectRequested());
          }
        });
```

For mapEventToState code snippet:

```
 @override
  Stream<SocketState> mapEventToState(SocketEvent event) async* {
 if (event is SocketConnectRequested) {
      yield* _mapSocketConnectRequestedToState();
    } else if (event is SocketDisconnectRequested) {
      yield* _mapSocketDisconnectRequestedToState(state);
    }
}
```

It calls only 2 times then it unable to trigger mapEventToState though it calls SocketEvent.

Thankful for any kind of help.